# Running libxlsxwriter on Windows

Tags: c, command-line, cygwin, msys2, libxlsxwriter

I am trying to use `libxlsxwriter`, but I can seem to get things to compile or run correctly.

I followed the directions for Windows using `Mingw-w64` and `msys2` available here: http://libxlsxwriter.github.io/getting_started.html.

I installed `msys2` from their website and updated everything using `pacman -Syu`. Then I installed `zlib` with the recommended:

```
# Install the dev tools for libxlsxwriter.
pacman -S git gcc make zlib-devel
```

Then I run the code to download and compile `libxlswriter`:

```
# Clone and build libxlsxwriter.
git clone https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter.git
cd libxlsxwriter/
make
make install
# run example
cd ..
cc myexcel.c -o myexcel -lxlsxwriter -lz
```

Now there is an executable named `myexcel` which should create an basic excel document, but when I double click it I get the errors:

```
The program can't start because msys-2.0.dll is missing from your computer.
```

I also get the error for missing `msys-z.dll`

I'm not sure what I did wrong or how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated

edit:

if I run:

```
make examples
./examples/hello
```

The hello world example successfully runs so things seem to be installed properly. I guess I just don't understand how to get it to run a user made .c

Comment: You have to add the path to the MSYS DLLs in Windows. ATM the dll is only in MSYS console path. Can you run the executable from MSYS console at least?

Comment: Yes it does! Makes sense thank you!

Comment: I added MinGW/bin to my PATH, but it still doesn't work. Do you know how to add MSYS to the console path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSYS console defines the path to MSYS commands & DLLs when opening the console: ex if MSYS is installed in `C:\msys64` it locally adds the path to `C:\msys64\usr\bin` but it does not add it to the Windows system PATH.

So if you click on the executable outside MSYS, it cannot find the DLLs because they are not in windows PATH.

many solutions:

1) add `C:\msys64\usr\bin` in user or computer PATH (edit environment variables). As a bonus you gain access to commands like `grep` in your windows CMD. As a drawback, there can be mixups/conflicts with commands like `find` or `sort`.

or

2) create a `myexcel.bat` file containing the following in your executable directory:

```
@echo off
set PATH=C:\msys64\usr\bin;%PATH%
%~PD0\myexcel.exe
```

(`%~PD0 prefix` allows to find the executable from the .bat path so if .bat file is run from another directory it still finds the executable)

3) copy the MSYS DLLs where your executable resides. Since the DLLs are in the same directory as the .exe Windows will find them. Recommended for a standalone distribution, not for personal use since it creates a lot of copies.

4) static linkage against MSYS .a libs. I don't know if this can be done for all libs. Cannot seem to find `libz.a` for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Minor note: path should be `C:\msys64\usr\bin`.